# how to make navigation bar work made with ul and li tags?

Tags: html, css

i am using ul an li as menu list.I am able to change color of menu item in hover and visited link but on active state color is not changing, would you tell me what could be the solution for that problem?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Chandan</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Resources/favicon.png" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />

 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="menu_line">
    <img src="../Resources/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">  

    <ul>
    <li value="home"><b><a href="portfolio_design.html" title="Home Page">Home</a></b></li>
    <li value="services"><b><a href="services.html" title="About services">Services</a></b></li>
    <li value="portfolio"><b><a href="portfolio.html" title="Porfile">Portfolio</a></b></li>
    <li value="blog"><b><a href="blog.html" title="Blog area">Blog</a></b></li>
    <li value="hire_me"><b><a href="hire_me.html" title="Hire for a project" >Hire me</a></b>              

     </li>
    </ul>

    </div><!--menu line end here-->


</div><!--header end here-->
</div><!--container end here-->

</body>
</html>

#css FIle*

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

  #logo
 {  
     margin:0 auto;
 float:left;
 height:55px;
 width:60px;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
  }

  ul
  { 

 margin:17px auto;
 float:right;
  }

 li
  {
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 25px;

 }

  .menu_line{
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top:60px;
   margin-left:120px;
   height:55px;
   width:730px;
   float:left;
   border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
   }
   .container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 998px;
  background-position:center;
   }

  .header
   {    
   margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#f82424;
  margin-top:-8px;
  margin-left:-8px;
  height:660px;
  width:1007px;
  background-position:center;

   }
  li a
  {
  color:#fcb1b1;
  text-decoration:none;
  }

   li a:hover
   {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }

  li a:active
   {
   color:#fff;
   text-decoration:underline;
   }
```

Comment: put your code on jsfiddle. I'll check it

Comment: We're going to need to see some code before we can help. Try creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Provide the content of your CSS file as well.

Comment: i have post the codes review it and please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: There isn't enough CSS to diagnose the issue in the code currently submitted,

Comment: Where is your css for hover?

Comment: `<li value="home">`? oO' http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp

Comment: i have just posted css file

Comment: You have defined the `:active` color the same as `:hover` why would it change? I think you may have misunderstood what `:active` does.

Comment: Your code is working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/0ots6cgb/ (slight change in :active css). What do you expect from it?

Comment: i want to change color of menu item when any page is selected untill user is in that page ..like if he is in home page then color would be white for home link and other will be dim and same for other links also when thet are selected

Comment: If you are, as you commented in answers "at begginers level" then maybe put a little bit more effort into reading documentation and maybe some tutorials? There're plenty of them online. What you need is to use classes, like in Farshad answer, and separate template for each view (unless you're using PHP for example).

Comment: thats exactly gentleman i agree wit you. but right now i am searching for the solution in many poratls but not able to get the solution. link is converting to color after clicking it only at the time of selection it is showing different color not after that but i am alreday in that page

Comment: almost first search from google: http://www.jacorre.com/tutorial/css-navigation-menus/

Answer (score -1):

This might help

```
    #menu_line .active a {
    background-color:#FFD700;
    }
```

Comment: please provide solution according to my code, becoz i am at begginers level

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution in css : 
I have edited your code at styles and menu items

simply you must set `class="active"` to each `li` element you want to show active
I have added the `class="active"` to the service menu item.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="menu_line">
    <img src="../Resources/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">  

    <ul>
    <li value="home"><b><a href="portfolio_design.html" title="Home Page">Home</a></b></li>
    <li value="services" class="active" ><b><a href="services.html" title="About services">Services</a></b></li>
    <li value="portfolio"><b><a href="portfolio.html" title="Porfile">Portfolio</a></b></li>
    <li value="blog"><b><a href="blog.html" title="Blog area">Blog</a></b></li>
    <li value="hire_me"><b><a href="hire_me.html" title="Hire for a project" >Hire me</a></b>              

     </li>
    </ul>

    </div><!--menu line end here-->


</div><!--header end here-->
</div><!--container end here-->
```

**CSS**

```
  #logo
 {  
     margin:0 auto;
 float:left;
 height:55px;
 width:60px;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
  }

  ul
  { 

 margin:17px auto;
 float:right;
  }

 li
  {
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 25px;

 }

  .menu_line{
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top:60px;
   margin-left:120px;
   height:55px;
   width:730px;
   float:left;
   border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
   }
   .container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 998px;
  background-position:center;
   }

  .header
   {    
   margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#f82424;
  margin-top:-8px;
  margin-left:-8px;
  height:660px;
  width:1007px;
  background-position:center;

   }



 li a,
 li a:hover,
 li a:active {
   color:#fff;
   text-decoration:underline;

}

 li.active a, 
 li.active a:hover, 
 li.active a:active {
  background: #323637;
}
```

Comment: please provide code according to my code becoz i am at begginers level i dont have so much idea

Comment: simply you must set `class="active"` to each `li` element you want to show active